# Npm is not run properly

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, vite

[image]

```
D:\coding\coding\website\Web_Projects\meme_generator> npm create vite@latest
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\shivr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-11T16_24_47_134Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I once had this same error when creating a Sveltekit project. you could try running:

```
npm install -g npm@latest

npm cache clean --force
```

and then

```
npm create vite@latest my-project

npm install mongoose --save
```

Comment: npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSEDnpm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'